# Удаление текста в не кавычек python

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста не смог найти вопрос на просторах интернета.
Имеется допустим строка *Программист воскликнул "Привет мир" и улыбнулся* вот в строке надо удалить все символы кроме тех который заключены в кавычки.

Comment: так надо было искать ответ. а не вопрос. Что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону регулярных выражений. Но если кавычки только один раз встречаются, то можно и проще сделать, просто через поиск символов. А, да, собственно можно через `split` сделать, например.

Comment: `re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', 'Программист воскликнул "Привет мир" и улыбнулся')`

Comment: @CrazyElf кавычки могут встречаться несколько раз

Answer (score 1):

Если кавычек **всегда** пара, то можно разбить строку с помощью `split()` метода и каждый нечетный член списка будет искомым

```py
>>> initial_str = "Программист воскликнул \"Привет мир\" и улыбнулся. \"Неа, 'HELLO WORLD' будет каноном\" ответил мир " 
>>> result = initial_str.split("\"")[1::2]
>>> print(result)
['Привет мир', "Неа, 'HELLO WORLD' будет каноном"]
```

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать так

```
s = 'Программист воскликнул "Привет мир" и улыбнулся'
print(s.split('"')[1::2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как кавычки открываются и закрываются одним и тем же символом, то найти и удалить текст, который не заключен в кавычки, будет не просто. Самый простой вариант, как уже указали в комментариях, - это найти текст между парой символов кавычек с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
from re import findall

s = 'Программист воскликнул "Привет", "мир" и улыбнулся'
res = findall(r'"(.*?)"', s)

print(res)  # ['Привет', 'мир']
```

Результат получается в виде списка строк.